# Select Multi rows from table B according to array value in table A

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, select, join

I have two tables (A, B), B table has a column *Fruit* which stores id values of table A rows as array, how can I output **IN ONE SELECT STATEMENT** the title of each id in table B, like that:

```
Table B :

id    title
1    Apple
2    Orange

Table A :
id   Fruit
1    1,2
```

result:

```
A.id  A.Fruit
1      Apple,Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(b.title)
FROm tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id , a.Fruit)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: sorry, but it didn't work, this is error message:
Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
I tried to put at the end of statement this : group by a.fruit , and the output wasn't correct they was mixed

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Fixed. Check last `GROUP BY` line

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Fruit FROM Table B WHERE Fruit IN (SELECT Fruit FROM Table A);` I don't know if this will work for you but I hope it helps. You will probably need to use **Subqueries**.